# Property or method X is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In console I see following messages:

Property or method `Id` is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property

How to get rid of it?

```html
<template>
  <v-content>
    <v-container grid-list-md text-xs-center>
      <v-layout v-for="person in people" :key="person.Id" row wrap>
        <v-flex :key="Id" sm1 hidden-xs-only>
          <v-card-text class="px-0">{{ person.Id }}</v-card-text>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-content>
<template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      people: null 
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    axiosInstance.get("person").then(response => {      
      this.people = response.data.persons;
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `:key="Id"` is the culprit. You haven't defined an `Id` in your Vue instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<v-flex :key="Id" sm1 hidden-xs-only>
```

`:key` is another syntax for `v-bind:key`, which is supposed to contain javascript code. In your case, Id is not defined. You probably wanted to use 'Id' string literal.

Use either

```html
<v-flex :key="'Id'" sm1 hidden-xs-only>
```

or

```html
<v-flex key="Id" sm1 hidden-xs-only>
```

or define an `Id` data in your vue instance.